# Как сделать такие овальные фоны?

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть такое изображение сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фоны там полупрозрачные и фигурные. За ними картинки. Как сделать такие фоны?

Comment: что у Вас не получается?

Comment: Не могу понять - это png вставляется как фон или нужно обрезать так через svg. Как PNG вставить понятно. А вот как с помощью SVG это сделать не знаю.

Comment: svg можно в векторном редакторе или можно ручками код написать..

Comment: У меня макет в PSD формате не знаю как это сделать

Comment: может что-то такое поможет? https://www.aconvert.com/image/psd-to-svg/

Comment: А если я эти фоны попробую сделать с помощью PNG это будет нормально? Просто делаю заказчику.

Comment: боюсь они огромные получатся

Comment: @Denis у меня в личке есть email скинь туда этот psd и в субботу я сделаю и вышлю  результат с подробным описанием что и как делал и даже видео запишу

Comment: В субботу уже будет поздно (